# Kentico 12 - Limit Page Selector by a given page type

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc

Is it possible to limit the new widget Page Selector by a given page type? I know you can set it to load a specific path using EditingComponentProperty(nameof(PageSelectorProperties.RootPath) but can't see a way to limit by page type.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't, just by path i'm afraid.  Not sure if Kentico is working on it, it would be nice to have as we have run into the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

You could always add a new widget property

**In your model properties class**

```
[EditingComponent(TextInputComponent.IDENTIFIER, Order = 0, Label = "Page Selector Class")]
public string PageSelectorClass { get; set; }
```

**In your controller**

```
var pages = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments(GetProperties().PageSelector)
//any other LINQ statements you need
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work? I need to filter the actual page selector, not do something with what was selected.

Comment: @mp3duck O so you want to restrict it so you can only select a specific page type. As far as I know this isn't possible. You'd have to [create your own form component](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/form-builder-development/developing-form-components/example-developing-a-custom-form-component).